# getting a redraw for a second <select>

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have two lists displaying on a web page:
(List of Clients)
(List of Projects)

When the user changes his selection in the client list, I repopulate the Project list.  I make a jquery call to php/mysql to fetch the projects relating to this client and then I use this data to set the options for the client `<select>`.  Unfortunately changing the list contents for the project `<select>` element does not cause the display for this element to change like setting the `innerHTML` for a text element would.

I can force a page refresh and everything looks fine, but I would prefer not to have to refresh the page.  Is there a way to cause a `<select>` element to redraw?

Here is a set of HTML/javascript that has the problem.  At the bottom of function BuildProjectList() it can be seen that I have tried populating the Project list in 2 ways, by setting innerHTML or by building the list of options.  In either case the display of the Project List does not update when I change its contents in response to a change of selection in the client list.  But if after this you change the selection in the project list, the display does update and you can verify that the underlying data for the Project list has in fact changed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Test List ....</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function BuildClientList()
{
    var uiEl = document.getElementById('uidCl');
    var aUidClient = new Array(3);

    aUidClient[0] = ['101', 'Client 1'];
    aUidClient[1] = ['102', 'Client 2'];
    aUidClient[2] = ['102', 'Client 3'];

    uiEl.options.length = 0;
    var cClient = aUidClient.length;
    for (iRow = 0; iRow < cClient; iRow++)
    {
        uiEl.options[iRow] = new Option(aUidClient[iRow][1], aUidClient[iRow][0]);
    }
}

function BuildProjectList()
{
    iClient = document.getElementById('uidCl').selectedIndex;
    var uiEl = document.getElementById('uidPr');
    var aUidProject = new Array(3);
    switch (iClient)
    {
        case 0:
        aUidProject[0] = ['101', '1Project 1'];
        aUidProject[1] = ['102', '1Project 2'];
        aUidProject[2] = ['103', '1Project 3'];
        break;
        case 1:
        aUidProject[0] = ['201', '2Project 1'];
        aUidProject[1] = ['202', '2Project 2'];
        aUidProject[2] = ['203', '2Project 3'];
        break;
        default:
        aUidProject[0] = ['301', '3Project 1'];
        aUidProject[1] = ['302', '3Project 2'];
        aUidProject[2] = ['303', '3Project 3'];
    }


    uiEl.options.length = 0;
    var cProject = aUidProject.length;
    var strInner = "";
    for (iRow = 0; iRow < cProject; iRow++)
    {
        uiEl.options[iRow] = new Option(aUidProject[iRow][1], aUidProject[iRow][0]);
        strInner += "<option value=\"" + aUidProject[iRow][0] + "\">" + 
            aUidProject[iRow][1] + "</option>";
    }
//  uiEl.innerHTML = strInner;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<input type="hidden" id="id_user_info" name="id_user_info" value="1" />
   <label for="s_client" class="select ui-hidden-accessible">Client...</label>
   <select data-overlay-theme="a" data-native-menu="false" name="uidCl" id="uidCl" onChange="BuildProjectList()">
<script type="text/javascript">
BuildClientList();
</script>
</select>


</div><div data-role="fieldcontain">
<input type="hidden" id="id_proj" name="id_proj" value="2" />
   <label for="s_proj" class="select ui-hidden-accessible">Project...</label>
   <select data-overlay-theme="a" data-native-menu="false" name="uidPr" id="uidPr" >
<script type="text/javascript">
BuildProjectList();
</script>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It actually should... please post your code and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: Please provide some code samples.

Comment: From your question "Unfortunately changing the list contents for the client element does not cause" part is not clear. Why are you changing  the client list elements? By changing you mean the selectedIndex? It's possible to trigger change event with jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ maybe that'all you need to redraw the projects list. Seeing some would also help.

Comment: I've added a set of HTML/javascript that displays the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use jquery to set in index in the  list and refresh the display.  The javascript function below shows how:

```
// set the index for a <select> element
function SetIndex(eid, i)
{
    var strEid = "#" + eid;
    var menuSelect = $(strEid);
    menuSelect[0].selectedIndex = i;
    menuSelect.selectmenu("refresh");
}
```